# Corejava to print unique elements from two arryas

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I want  a core java program to find unique elements between two arrays. 
Example:
Array1 - 9, 5,3,23,2,5
Array2 - 19, 5,3,23,24,53

output of unique elements from both of the array's should print as: 9, 2, 19, 24, 53

pls help me to write the program with accurate loops.

NOTE: Dont want to handle the same program using any of the collections and want to be done using only loops. Thanks

Comment: Are your numbers limited to be within a certain range? (i.e. 1-25)

Comment: tried with rotating from first array for every element from first array, checked with each element with second array elements. But I want the reverse also (like printing from second array as well)

Comment: yes durron, it is fixed but need to use minimal loops. thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with using collections for this, anyway?  You just use a Map<int,int> to track the items and their count, and then spit out the keys with a matching value of 1.  Although there's probably a better collection than that, even...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use at least 2 loops.

```
public void uniqueM(int arrayA[], int arrayB[]){
    boolean uniqueA = true, uniqueB = true;
    int high_size = arrayA.length, low_size = arrayB.length;

   if(arrayA.length < arrayB.length){
     low_size = arrayA.length;
     high_size = arrayB.length;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < high_size; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < low_size;j++)
      {
         if(i < arrayA.length && arrayA[i] == arrayB[j]) uniqueA = false;
         if(i < arrayB.length && arrayB[i] == arrayA[j]) uniqueB = false;
      }
       if(uniqueA && i < arrayA.length) System.out.println(arrayA[i]);
       if(uniqueB && i < arrayB.length) System.out.println(arrayB[i]);

       uniqueA = true;
       uniqueB = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tweak the size of the `counter` array and the `offset` variable based on what range your legal integers can fall in. But this doesn't use anything in the `java.util` API, only loops.

```
public static int[] uniques(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    // assuming your integers are 0-53, you'd have to modify this if it's different
    int[] counter = new int[54];

    // offset needs to be changed based on if negative numbers are allowed
    int offset = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        counter[array1[i] + offset]++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        counter[array2[i] + offset]++;
    }

    int numUniques = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
        if(counter[i] == 1) numUniques++;
    }

    int[] uniqueArray = new int[numUniques];
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
        if(counter[i] == 1) uniqueArray[index++] = i;
    }

    return uniqueArray;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me whats happening here? for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        counter[array1[i] + offset]++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        counter[array2[i] + offset]++;
    }

Comment: I think I understand, for every element index it maintains counter. Thanks, this is a nice program

Comment: Yes, exactly, glad I could help